Do the higher direct image sheaves of a branched holomorphic covering vanish?
To be specific, I am interested in the following situation.
Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a branched holomorphic covering of Riemann surfaces and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf over $X$ (although even restricting to the case of a holomorphic vector bundle would be enough for me.)
I am interested in computing the higher direct image sheaves $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ under such a covering map to use in a computation involving the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem.
By analogy with the algebraic geometry literature, given the map $f$ is finite I would think that the higher direct images vanish for $i>0$?
However, I'm not sure how one would go about showing this in the complex setting. Any advice or resources specifically pertaining to the complex setting would be appreciated.

I’m not sure, but I think this situation is locally (over $Y$) isomorphic to a direct union of copies of $z \in D \mapsto z^n \in D$, where $D$ is the open unit disk, so it’s enough to treat this case

In general, the basic machinery for direct image sheaves is also established on complex spaces, allowing for the OP's indicated result for finite maps between analytic spaces to go through. I don't have a good reference at hand, though; see Grauert's seminal 1960 article numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1960__5__5_0/ for the general machinery.
Here's an alternative, quick (overkill?) argument for Riemann surfaces: Quite generally, $R^if_*F$ is the sheaf associated with the pre-sheaf $U\mapsto H^i(f^{-1}U,F)$. But for any non-empty open $U$ on the base, $f^{-1}U$ is a disjoint union of connected open Riemann surfaces, hence Stein (by Behnke--Stein, 1947). Thus, $H^i(f^{-1}U,F)=0$ for $i>0$ by Cartan's Theorem B.
